# Getting File Url When A File Is Going To Download

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

### My Work So FAR

Manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Extension For PyIDM",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": " An Open Source Alternative Of IDM",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/favicon-16x16.png",
        "48": "icons/android-icon-48x48.png",
       "120": "icons/apple-icon-120x120.png" 
             },
    "author" : ["Harshil Pandey","@PyIDM"],
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "downloads"
      ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js","pyidm_extension.js","webextension.js"]
    }}
```

Background.js

```
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    //window.open("install.html")
    window.open('install.html','height=480,width=640', false);
  });

chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function() {
    var r = confirm("Do you Want To Download"+ File + " Using PyIDM");
    if (r == true) {
      var final = chrome.downloads.onCreated.finalUrl;
      alert(final + " I Am working");
      //alert("You pressed OK!");
    } else {
      //alert("You pressed Cancel!");
    }
  }
 )
```

### Problem

How to Get The Url OF The File That IS Going Downloads
And The File NAme

What i am using to know if a file is going to download: chrome.downloads.onCreated

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) for onCreated event: it has a parameter with all that info.

Comment: Hey! As You Said I Saw Documentation But When I Tried chrome.downloads.finalUrl() I AM NOt Able To Get Plz Help

Comment: That's not what my comment said. Read it carefully. The parameter is described in detail when you click it on the documentation page and it leads [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#type-DownloadItem). You also should fix your code to actually use that parameter so `function()` should become `function(info)`

Comment: hey can you tell where the code should be fixed?

Comment: Hey! I Changed chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function() { To chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function(DownloadItem,finalUrl) { Are You Talking About This But How to Use it after applying in parameter?

Comment: That's not what I wrote again. I can't help you. Please wait for someone else.